# Jboss port configuration on Intellij Idea error

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm trying to run my application on Jboss App Server by Intellij Idea12. I've done configuration:
[image]

but As you can see in the picture I got the error `Management Port Configuration not found`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Possible cause maybe an invalid configuration file "standalone.xml" or any other config file that you are using.
I've put a tag at the wrong place and got the same error.

Comment: That will teach me for editing the standalone.xml with just notepad :)

Comment: My case is that coworker (win7) sent me (Ubuntu) standalone.xml and encoding got messed up.

Comment: Starting the standalone.bat (/bin/standalone.bat) can give a clue to where the invalid character is, in my case spelling out the offending character and line number

Answer (score 14):

It seems that IntelliJ IDEA was not able to read offset value from "standalone.xml".
to solve it, just set Port offset to 0 in Configuration window, it will manually add additional VM option:  -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=0

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Your standalone xml may be malformed in some way. Check to see if you have special characters that you will have to escape or extra closing or opening tags etc.

Comment: I mixed up xml with vim

Answer (score 3):

look for this in your standalone.xml

socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="9999"

Source:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-77592

Answer (score 3):

My case was that there was no config.

Folder c:\jboss-eap-6.4.6\standalone\configuration\ was without configuration files. There was only one folder org.6.4.0, where was the configuration.

The solution was to copy configuration files from c:\jboss-eap-6.4.6\standalone\configuration\org.6.4.0\ to c:\jboss-eap-6.4.6\standalone\configuration\

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `standalone.xml` was corrupted (probably cause Idea froze and had to do hard shutdown). So I went to `standalone_xml_history` and copied `standalone.xml` from the day before. And it started to work normally again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:
I typed 9990 in port offset of Run/Debug Configurations and it solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but have no idea what your setup looks like so the solution might not be the same. Also since your question is quite old you've probably figured out the answer by now.

Anyways.. In case anyone else happens to stumble upon this issue, I solved it this way: 
We use Puppet in our project and I had changed a couple of `.yaml` files where I added some URLs. The URLs contained `&` which had to be `&amp;` and IntelliJ didn't notify me that this was the issue. It broke JBoss and everything.

Try running JBoss `standalone.sh` in the terminal and see if you get a Stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was added in standalone.xml in `<deployments>` section the following:

```
<deployment name="xxx-ear-1.0.ear" runtime-name="xxx-ear-1.0.ear">
 <fs-archive path="path\xxx-ear-1.0.ear"/>
</deployment>
```

I've removed this and worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be happening due to a parsing error in your configuration files.

Start your JBoss/WildFly in the command line, so that you would see more details if this is happening because of a configuration (or parsing) error.

- On Windows run `{JBOSS_HOME}/bin/standalone.bat` file so that it would open up a console window and try to start up your application server.
- Look for any ERROR in the log and see if it is related to configuration.
- For example:

  ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: 
  org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration

If this doesn't help, have a look at open the ports - maybe the port JBoss/WildFly is configured to is already used by some other application.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sute you had provided valid configuration file, may be your configuration file contains misplaced tag/element entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I went to the standalone directory, I saw that the standalone.xml file was renamed as standalone.xml.tmp.

So I just renamed it as standalone.xml and when I started my Intellij again, everything was ok. If it's already not after that, you can delete and build a new running configuration after starting Intellij

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, adding the VM options to point to standalone config files fixed my issue

```
/Users/XXX/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-16.0.0.Final.XXX.2019.152-node1/standalone/configuration/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "Management Port Configuration not found" when i was trying to boot up my jboss.

In my case i had accidentally deleted my standalone.xml. When i put it back all went fine. Another person had same issue turned out was some malformed tag in the standalone.xml.

Answer (score 0):

My standalone.xml file has been renamed to standalone.xml.tmp automatically. Rename it back to standalone.xml and it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ can't overwrite standalone.xml.
That means that you have opened standalone.xml with other editor.
Close standalone.xml and try again.